# What is the proper way to get binary data from python 2.7 into a C module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-extension

I am reading binary data from a file in python and trying to send that data to a c module.  In python the data is read like so

```
file = open("data", "rb")
data = file.read()
```

I want the data as a pointer to a buffer and a length in c if possible.  I am using PyArg_ParseTuple to get the parameters in the c module.  I noticed in python 3+ there is a y/y*/y# format specifier for binary data but I need the equivalent way of doing it in python 2.7.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Comment: @GuySirton -- It looks to me like OP is trying to use the [C-API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/)

Comment: correct, and actually specifically to avoid using ctypes, using the buffer api looks like the right way to go, I was also able to get the results I wanted with the s# format string using PyArg_ParseTuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should investigate the [Buffer Api](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html).

From the docs:

> These functions can be used by an object to expose its data in a raw, byte-oriented format. Clients of the object can use the buffer interface to access the object data directly, without needing to copy it first.
>
> Two examples of objects that support the buffer interface are strings and arrays. The string object exposes the character contents in the buffer interface’s byte-oriented form. An array can also expose its contents, but it should be noted that array elements may be multi-byte values.

For example (in C++):

```
void* ExtractBuffer(PyObject* bufferInterfaceObject, Py_buffer& bufferStruct)
{
    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(bufferInterfaceObject, &bufferStruct, PyBUF_SIMPLE) == -1)
        return 0;

    return (void*)bufferStruct.buf;
}
```

Do not forget to release the bufferStruct when you no longer need it:

```
PyBuffer_Release(&bufferStruct);
```